# Create powerpoint presentation using c++ in windows

Tags: c++, powerpoint

I am trying to use windows api and create a powerpoint presentation and save the presentation in a pps format. For example a.pps. then I want to write a program in Visual Studio, create a.pps as a process and execute it, try to manipulate with slides and then terminate the process.

Is there such a way or can anyone guide me to the right way?

Comment: WinAPI offers no methods for creating PPS files.  Depending on what specifically you need to do, you might be able to use COM automation and have PowerPoint itself do the work for you.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg:Does this mean that I cant use WinAPI to create power point slides? I will try to find the way but up to now I couldnt

Comment: You can't use WinAPI to create PowerPoint slides.  If PowerPoint is installed on the Windows system, you can call *its* methods to create slides though.  If PowerPoint isn't available, it gets a great deal more complicated.